# SQL - Show Data of Table1(PK) without having data in Table2(FK)

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

there are two tables Customer and Fees `(PK customer.CustomerID -> Fees.CustomerId FK)`
there  are customers in `Customer` table.
where in table `Fees` there is no data of current month.
without inserting data in Fees table of current month
i want to show the Customer details from Customer table of whom have not paid the fees of current month.

something like:

```
if(Convert(varchar(3),MonthFee, 109) != convert(varchar(3),getdate(),109))
BEGIN
select Customer.CustomerId as ID, Customer.CustomerName as Name, Customer.Phone as [Phone No], 'UnPaid' as [Pay Status], convert(varchar(3),getdate(),109) as [Month], YEAR(GETDATE()) as [Year]
from Customer inner join Fees on Customer.CustomerId = Fees.CustomerId Where FeeMonth = null

END
```

Help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Simply use LEFT JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN in the sql query. That would do the trick.

Comment: you can't use an inner join. if they haven't paid fees, there won't be any records in the fees table to join against...

Comment: I'd use a left join and an appropriate where clause and then check for fees.customerId is null

Comment: @AT-2016  But that `IF` condition is not working. It is giving error like "invalid column name FeeMonth"
Edit: i have checked after giving the correct column name.

How do i resolve it? and do i need the if condition or not?

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison
I want to check for Fees.FeeMonth is null (current month) then show that customer as 'unpaid'

Comment: IF isn't necessary in this case if you are just trying to get the data that aren't in the second table. LEFT JOIN will do the work. Again if you don't want to show the null values, better use the CASE in the query.

Comment: Sorry, @KenWhite i edited the question/heading

Comment: Just make your where clause exclude items that are not in the current month ... >= the first day of the month would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query..

```
 select Customer.CustomerId as ID,  
   Customer.CustomerName as Name, 
   Customer.Phone as   [Phone No],
    'UnPaid' as [Pay Status],   
     convert(varchar(3),getdate(),109) as [Month],   
    YEAR(GETDATE()) as [Year]
  from Customer 
  Where not exists(select 1 from  Fees 
      Where Customer.CustomerId = Fees.CustomerId 
       And    Month( FeeMonth )= month(getdate())
       And year(FeeMonth)=year(getdate())
```

Comment: with couple of changes your query did the trick. Thanks alot my friend. Thanks ALOT! ^^ :)

why don't you join us on  CHAT on stackoverflow in "SQL" channel. :)

Comment: You are always welcome.. I haven't used chat and will make a try for sure.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different type of join. simplest would be to use right join as shown below

```
select Customer.CustomerId as ID, Customer.CustomerName as Name, Customer.Phone as [Phone No], 'UnPaid' as [Pay Status], convert(varchar(3),getdate(),109) as [Month], YEAR(GETDATE()) as [Year]
from Fees 
right join Customer on Fees.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId Where FeeMonth = null
```